# ¿Cómo recupero los datos de un commit que se salió de la rama?

Tags: git

Creo que hice mal un `commit` y quedó fuera de la rama `main`, en la que estaba trabajando.

Cuando me posicioné en la rama main para subir los cambios,
faltaban modificaciones al codigo
Apliqué `git branch` y me mostro la rama main abajo de head:

- *(HEAD detached at ee62459)*
- *main*

¿Cómo podría añadir los cambios de `ee62459` a `main`?

Comment: *habían cambios que no tenía por estar en...* -> ¿Por estar en donde?...

Comment: modifique la respuesta, habia cambios que me faltaban que se supone que estaban en la rama main

Comment: checa que tu cambios con git status. si tienes cambios puedes puedes agregar con git add . y luego git commit -m "tu_mensaje"  y luego git push a tu rama.

Answer (score 1):

Estas en `detached HEAD state`, es decir, trabajando sin una rama asociada. Si quieres que tu rama `main` **local** quede ahí (asumiendo que se quedó atrás en la historia de donde estás parado), puedes forzar mover el apuntador:

```
git branch -f main # colocar la rama main aqui donde estoy
git checkout main
```

Y listo, ya la rama **local** quedó donde estabas parado.

Otra forma de hacerlo, con más pasos y sin forzar el movimiento de la rama es usando una rama temporal donde estás parado:

```
git branch temporal
git checkout main
git merge temporal
# ya podemos borrar la rama temporal
git branch -d temporal
```

Si `main` estaba apuntando a un ancestro de `temporal` entonces git debería hacer un *fast-forward*, de lo contrario debe hacer un *merge*.